# Creating Excel File

Tags: c#, windows, excel, windows-phone-7

Well, I didn't find any libs to create Excel file in Windows Phone 7 and the default libs for Excel are not working because they weren't compile for it.

Does any of you guys know how to do this?

Comment: I really doubt you can do this. Can't you use a web service layer and have the heavy work done on the server? If so, in the server, you can surely use the OpenXML SDK to handle office files.

Comment: if your file is simple enough you could go for a csv file instead of a full fledged excel sheet

Comment: I was trying to avoid any online operation, and unfortunatelly it's my sheet isn't tha simple =/ I hope someone come up with a solution.

Comment: You could get the [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com) source code and try to compile it for WP7...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel is able to open many different kinds of files beyond the .xls or .xlsx. Most common is CSV; it's dead simple but not very capable, and I would avoid it for all but the simplest applications.

A format I've used successfully is the [Symbolic Link (SYLK) format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYmbolic_LinK_%28SYLK%29). The .slk files open directly in Excel, and you can include cell formatting and formulas. It's easy to save out a file from Excel itself and use it as a template for creating your own files.

Comment: SYLK doesn't support Unicode, though, which probably makes it a poor choice nowadays.

Comment: Thats a good solution for my case, because I'm writing for only one country. Thanks

Comment: @Joey, I just tried it - when Excel 2010 wrote out the file it substituted a `?` for the Unicode `π`. Unfortunately you're right. I don't know how it would treat UTF-8 in the input but I expect it fares just as badly.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to struggle to find a library to do this simply because WP (as of 7.1) doesn't include the `System.IO.Packaging` namespace, which most libraries will depend on to read/write docx/xlsx/etc files.