# launching other programs or applications on a windows phone7

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7-emulator

I am new to the windows phone programming and silver light. Is there any way to start excel inside an application in windows phone 7.Now i am writing a program and need to store some data on excel file.Is there any methods
Thanks in advance
Prasad

Answer (score 0):

You can't open an Excel file your app creates directly because each app runs in its own isolated sandbox. You might have luck creating your Excel file and [uploading to the user's SkyDrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272765/programmatic-access-of-skydrive). The Office hub will then be able to download and open it.

Note that your options for creating an Excel file are limited: [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880314/creating-excel-file).